# Função para exibir ultimo visto (data atual)- Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,

Através da função abaixo, pretendo exibir o ultimo visto.

Porem, está exibindo o ultimo mês, ao invés de exibir o mês atual.

Por exemplo, estou enviando a data atual, mas está retornando o mês 2.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01hbnwca/)

```js
let ret = mDate('2019-03-12 17:41:19').lastSeenFormat()
console.log('last seen ' + ret);

alert('last seen ' + ret);

// code
function mDate(dateString){
 
 let date = dateString ? new Date(dateString) : new Date();

 let dualize = (x) => x < 10 ? "0" + x : x;
 let getTime = () => dualize(date.getHours()) + ":" + dualize(date.getMinutes());
 let getDate = () => dualize(date.getDate()) + "/" + dualize(date.getMonth()) + "/" + dualize(date.getFullYear());

 return {
  subtract: (otherDateString) => {
   return date - new Date(otherDateString);
  },
  lastSeenFormat: () => {
   let dateDiff = Math.round(new Date() - date) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
   let value = (dateDiff === 0) ? "today" : (dateDiff === 1) ? "yesterday" : getDate();
   return value + " at " + getTime();
  },
  chatListFormat: () => {
   let dateDiff = Math.round((new Date() - date) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
   if (dateDiff === 0) {
    return getTime();
   } else if (dateDiff === 1) {
    return "Yesterday";
   } else {
    return getDate();
   }
  },
  getDate: () => {
   return getDate();
  },
  getTime: () => {
   return getTime();
  },
  toString:() => {
   return date.toString().substr(4, 20);
  },
 };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A função "getMonth()" do objeto Date retorna o numero do mês começando por zero, por isso Jan=0, Fev=1, Mar=2 até Dez=11.

Você só precisa levar isso em conta que de resto não tem nada de errado com seu script.

Comment: Isto não seria a solução `getMonth() + 1` pois assim, não exibiria a string `today`.

Comment: Sim, é o jeito mais simples.